# Sharding: What happens if an individual transaction is validated in multiple committees?

Tags: transactions, sharding, validators

In **Sharding** idea, miners are divided into multiple smaller groups (committees), each of which, processes a subset of transactions that are distributed in the entire network.

The question is how to decide an individual transaction (let's say `tx_i`) should be validated by which committee? And what happens if this transaction is processed and validated by multiple committees simultaneously?

**P.S.** If the question is not still enough clear, please let me know.